# I want to print "Hello" even before main() is executed

Tags: java

I want to print `"Hello"` even before `main()` is executed in Java Program. Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: Use a static block in the class that contains the `main`.

Comment: Just curiosity or some real functional requirement to accomplish?

Comment: @Nambari It's perfectly possible. He never said he didn't want main to execute at all.

Comment: i was dying to answer this question and get chance of precious  reversal badge but dup rune my life

Comment: @NullPoiиteя It's simply not a duplicate, he never said he didn't want a main method.

Comment: @arshajii: yeah, misread. you are correct. It is possible.

Comment: @arshajii but dup ans this question too :)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя That doesn't matter, this *question* is not a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 10):

What you need is a `static` keyword. One of the options is to use static function as initializer to static variable.

```
class Main {
  public static int value = printHello();
  public static int printHello() { 
    System.out.println("Hello"); 
    return 0;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Main started");
  }
}
```

`value` is a static variable so initialized before `main` function execution. This program prints:

```
Hello
Main started
```

Moreover, you can even simplify this by calling `printHello()` even without variable initialization like in the following:

```
static {
  printHello();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

public class Sample {

```
static {

    System.out.println("Hello first statement executed first ");
}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Main started");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a static block:

```
static {
    System.out.println("hello");
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    System.out.println("After hello");
}
```

Output:

```
hello
after hello
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Test {
  static {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Inside Main");
  }
}
```

Outputs

```
Hello
Inside Main
```

Comment: Since I wrote the same and agree with my answer too: +1. Just easy and short with no methods

Answer (score 1):

Print the statement inside a static block of code. Static blocks get executed when the class gets loaded into the memory and even before the creation of an object. Hence it will be executed before the main() method. And it will be executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using static block, you can also try instrumentation and premain

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, for my application, since I knew the static trick, but I wanted to run something even before that. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;


class ABCD {

    public static int k= printit();

    public static  int printit(){

        System.out.println("Hello it will be printed before MAIN");
        return 0;

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Main method is Executed");

    }
}
```

Static variables are initialized in the start of execution of program . So to initialize it will call **printit();** function which will be executed and **"Hello it will be printed before MAIN"** will be printed and in last function will  return value '0' and finally after this main block will be executed.

Final Output :

```
Hello it willl be printed before MAIN
Main method is Executed
```

Comment: Please update your answer to explain how this code block addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
class One{
    public One() {
        System.out.println("Before main");
    }   
}

class Two extends One{
    public Two() {
        super();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object abj = new Two();
        System.out.println("in the main");
    }
}
```

Here in run configuration, class Two would be the main class.

Comment: if i write a print statement before Object creation of Two class in main function then this will not work. example : `System.out.println("first line");
        Object abj = new Two();`